# Could someone modify my code? I need to read a singe string and store it into an array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, input

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
int a = 0, len1 = 0, len2 = 0;
int BUFSIZE = 1000;
char *string1[1];
char *string2[1];
FILE *fp1 = fopen("input1.txt", "r");
FILE *fp2 = fopen("input2.txt", "r");
if ((fp1 == 0)||(fp2 == 0))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening");
    return 0;
}
string1[a] = (char *)malloc(BUFSIZE);
string2[a] = (char *)malloc(BUFSIZE);
fgets(string1[0], BUFSIZE, fp1);
fgets(string2[0], BUFSIZE, fp2);
len1=strlen(string1[0]);
len2=strlen(string2[0]);

printf("%c\n", string1[0][4]);
printf("Output: \n");
srand(time(NULL));
printf("%s\n", string1[0]);
printf("%s\n", string2[0]);
printf("\n");
printf("%d %d", len1, len2); 
printf("\n");

free(string1[0]);
free(string2[0]);
int x=0;
scanf("%d", &x);
fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);
return 0;
}
```

I need to read a string from a file and store it in an array. I need to read only one line of string, and each element of the array should be a character of the string. For example, if I read 'ABCDABC' into an array, then array[3] should be 'D'. But I don't really know how to do it, I modified some other's code, and get the above code. But I don't want to involve pointers and address stuff in my code. So could anyone tell me how to realize it without using pointers? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you not want to use pointers?

Comment: Because I'll have to make comparison of characters, so I have to operate on each character of the string. It would be a little tricky if pointers are involved.

Comment: It would be a lot trickier without them.  Pointers are wonderful things.  They are the key to understanding a lot about how the computer really works.  I advise you not to be scared of pointers.  Yours is the language of Ian Phillips and Oscar Toledo Gutierrez, now go forth and multiply your array, but only after you have read up on pointers.

Comment: I guess you are right. Pointers are tricky for me, since I really have a poor knowledge about them. But this is a class project, I have to finish it asap so I would like to avoid the stuff I am not familiar with.

Comment: I sympathise with that, but you need to understand the basics at some point, better earlier than later.  Read a good explanation of pointers, really slowly, absorbing it as you go along.  And when you come across an example with * in, make sure that you understand what the stars are doing before you hand it in, even if it compiles ;-).  You'll reap the benefits in your future class projects, and also come exam time.  For your current project, there is some good advice below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `char *` and `malloc`ed memory, you can also use plain `char[N]`. The changes are small, since a `char[N]` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element when it is passed to a function (likje `fgets` or `strlen`). The code would also only minimally change if you used plain `char*` for `string1` and `string2`, `char *string1 = malloc(BUFSIZE);`, the main difference here would be the `malloc` and the `free` at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 0, len1 = 0, len2 = 0;
    int BUFSIZE = 1000;

    // char *string1;
    // char *string2;

    // instead of one-element arrays of char*, let's just use char arrays

    char string1[BUFSIZE];
    char string2[BUFSIZE];

    // One pointer to check whether fgets succeeded
    char *suc;

    FILE *fp1 = fopen("input1.txt", "r");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("input2.txt", "r");
    if ((fp1 == 0)||(fp2 == 0))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening");
        return 0;
    }
    // No need for malloc, we have char arrays
    // string1 = (char *)malloc(BUFSIZE);
    // string2 = (char *)malloc(BUFSIZE);
    suc = fgets(string1, BUFSIZE, fp1);
    if (!suc) {
        // fgets failed, what now? exit?
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    suc = fgets(string2, BUFSIZE, fp2);
    if (!suc) {
        // see above
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    len1=strlen(string1);
    len2=strlen(string2);

    // is the read string long enough?
    if (len1 > 4) {
        printf("%c\n", string1[4]);
    }
    printf("Output: \n");
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("%s\n", string1);
    printf("%s\n", string2);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d %d", len1, len2); 
    printf("\n");

    // free is only for m/c/re-alloced memory
    // free(string1);
    // free(string2);
    int x=0;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one thing, when I use char string1[BUFSIZE], my compiler says 'expression must have a constant value', so I have to write it as char string1[1000], do you know what the problem may be? My compiler is MS Visual C++ 2012 Express.

Comment: Ah, Microsoft's C compiler doesn't support C99, and variable length arrays (where the length is given by a variable) are a feature added in C99. For compilers that don't support it, you must use a constant expression, maybe `#define BUFSIZE 1000` if you don't want to litter your code with magic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To read only a line you have to check for the character `'\n'`, you have to do it like this

```
char *readLine(char *fileName, int line)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char *code;
    size_t n,l;
    int c;

    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL; //could not open file

    code = malloc(1000);

    for(l = 0; l <= line; l++)
    {
        n = 0;
        while (c = fgetc(file)) != '\n')
        {
            code[n++] = (char) c;
        }
    }

    // don't forget to terminate with the null character
    code[n] = '\0';        

    return code;
}
```

this code brings the string of the x line of your document reading character by character the file until it finds the newline character x times.
you write something like this `char *string1 = readLine("C:\document.txt",1);`
if the second line is `"Sometext"` then `string[3] == 'e'`

Comment: You meant `fgetc` where you wrote `fgets`.